# Does polyglossia load old version of fontspec?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia

The `polyglossia` package loads `fontspec` with

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}[2010/06/08]
```

Does it mean that  it uses an old version of `fontspec` that does not have features of the latest version?

Comment: No, that means the fontspec needs to be newer thant that date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no that is a standard latex2e option that causes an error to be loaded if fontspec is older than that date. It does not affect the actual version that is loaded.